# Python3 Search for a key and return all parents and nested children based on weight

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python and got stuck on one DSA problem. I would like to search for a particular line and return all the parent and nested child lines if search is found.
example: a search for `"goodmorning"` should return `[hellothere, goodmorning, goodnight, sweetdreams]` *(The weight of potato is higher than mango)*

```py
data = {
    "abc": {
        "weight": 20,
        "line": "hellothere",
        "xyz": {
            "weight": 10,
            "line": "goodmorning",
            "potato": {
                "weight": 9,
                "line": "goodnight",
                "kiwi": {
                    "weight": 6, 
                    "line": "sweetdreams"
                    },
            },
            "mango": {
                "weight": 8,
                "line": "evening",
                "kiwi": {
                    "weight": 4, 
                    "line": "sweetevening"
                    },
            },
        },
        "bbb": {
            "weight": 6,
            "line": "morning",
            "orange": {
                "weight": 3, 
                "line": "night"
                },
        },
    },
    "ccc": {
        "weight": 10, 
        "line": "happydays", 
        "ddd": {
            "weight": 4, 
            "line": "happynights"
            }
        },
}
```

I do have the following code and it outputs: `['hellothere', 'goodmorning', 'evening', 'sweetevening']`. I am stuck on how to implement **`weight`** logic. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

```py
def search_line(data, search_for):
    result = []

    def _line_search(d, path):
        path = path + [d["line"]] if "line" in d else path
        if search_for in d.get("line", []) or search_for in path:
            result.append(path)
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                _line_search(v, path)
    _line_search(data, [])
    return result[-1] if len(result) else ""

lines = search_line(data, "goodmorning")
print(lines)
```

Comment: *and got stuck on one DSA problem* -- Your question has nothing to do with Digital Signature Algorithm, which is what the `dsa` tag means.  Removing the `dsa` tag.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to do it starting with DFS and then switching to choosing the mex weighted path as soon as the target line is found:

```
def get_weighted_path(node):
    max_weight = -1
    next_node = None
    next_line = None
    
    for key, value in node.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            if value["weight"] > max_weight:
                max_weight = value["weight"]
                next_node = value
                next_line = value["line"]
    
    if next_node is not None:
        path.append(next_line)
        get_weighted_path(next_node)


def dfs(node, search_for, is_found=False):
    for key, value in node.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            if not is_found:
                path.append(value["line"])
                if value["line"] == search_for:
                    # found our line, now going for biggest weights
                    get_weighted_path(value)
                    return True
                if dfs(value, search_for=search_for, is_found=False):
                    return True
                path.pop() # no success, this branch is useless
    return False


path = []

dfs(data, search_for="goodmorning")
path
```

Output:

```
['hellothere', 'goodmorning', 'goodnight', 'sweetdreams']
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> def search_line(data, search_term, result=[], current_weight=float('-inf')):
>     for key, value in data.items():
>         if isinstance(value, dict):
>             line = value.get('line')
>             weight = value.get('weight')
>             if line == search_term and weight > current_weight:
>                 result.append(line)
>                 current_weight = weight
>             else:
>                 if line:
>                     result.append(line)
>                 search_line(value, search_term, result, current_weight)
>         else:
>             if value == search_term and current_weight == float('-inf'):
>                 result.append(value)
>     return result
> ```

Comment: Hi Sami, your answer is incorrect and does not implement weight logic.

Comment: Hi Sami, thank you for updating your answer. Your code is giving: ['hellothere', 'goodmorning', 'morning', 'night', 'happydays', 'happynights']. However, the desired output is [hellothere, goodmorning, goodnight, sweetdreams]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).